# Installing jaxlib for cuda 11.8

Tags: ubuntu, pip, jax

I'm trying to install jax and jaxlib on my Ubuntu 18 with python 3.8 for snerg (https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/snerg). Unfortunately when I try to install jax and jaxlib for Cuda 11.8 with the following command :

```
pip install --upgrade jax jaxlib==0.1.69+cuda118 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_releases.html
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.4.14 Requires-Python >=3.9
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib==0.1.69+cuda118 (from versions: 0.1.32, 0.1.40, 0.1.41, 0.1.42, 0.1.43, 0.1.44, 0.1.46, 0.1.50, 0.1.51, 0.1.52, 0.1.55, 0.1.56, 0.1.57, 0.1.58, 0.1.59, 0.1.60, 0.1.61, 0.1.62, 0.1.63, 0.1.64, 0.1.65, 0.1.66, 0.1.67, 0.1.68, 0.1.69, 0.1.70, 0.1.71, 0.1.72, 0.1.73, 0.1.74, 0.1.75, 0.1.76, 0.3.0, 0.3.2, 0.3.5, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.10, 0.3.14, 0.3.15, 0.3.18, 0.3.20, 0.3.22, 0.3.24, 0.3.25, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.6, 0.4.7, 0.4.9, 0.4.10, 0.4.11, 0.4.12, 0.4.13)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib==0.1.69+cuda118
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jaxlib version 0.1.69 is quite old (it was released in July 2021) CUDA 11.8 was released over a year later, in September 2022. Thus I would not expect there to be pre-built binaries for jaxlib version 0.1.69 targeting CUDA 11.8.

If possible, your best bet would be to install a newer version of jaxlib, one which has builds targeting CUDA 11.8. The current jaxlib+CUDA GPU installation instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/google/jax#pip-installation-gpu-cuda-installed-via-pip-easier).

If for some reason you absolutely need this very old jaxlib version, you'll probably first have to install an older CUDA version on your system. The CUDA jaxlib installation instructions from jaxlib 0.1.69 can be found [here](https://github.com/google/jax/tree/jaxlib-v0.1.69#pip-installation-gpu-cuda): it looks like it was built to target CUDA 10.1-10.2, 11.0, or 11.1-11.3.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following instructions which are primarily obtained from the [source](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-jax):

Uninstall previous versions (if *any*):

```
$ pip uninstall jax jaxlib jaxtyping -y
```

Upgrade your pip:

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

Find out which CUDA is already installed on your machine:

```
$ nvidia-smi

Thu Jan  4 11:24:58 2024       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.129.03             Driver Version: 535.129.03   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA RTX A1000 6GB Lap...    Off | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   58C    P0              12W /  35W |      8MiB /  6144MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      3219      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            4MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Depending on the CUDA version of your machine( **wheels only available on linux** ), run ***EITHER*** of the following:

```
# CUDA 12.X installation
$ pip install --upgrade "jax[cuda12_pip]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html

#### OR ####

# CUDA 11.X installation
# Note: wheels only available on linux.
pip install --upgrade "jax[cuda11_pip]" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
```

To double check if you have have successfully configured the gpu:

```
$ python -c "import jax; print(f'Jax backend: {jax.default_backend()}')"
Jax backend: gpu
```